# Show that random variable are independent

Tags: real-analysis, probability, independence

> Let $(X_i)_{i \geq 1}$ be independent random variables which follow the uniform law on $\{1,...,n\}$. Now we defined the random variable $\forall k \leq n, Y_k = \inf_{m \geq 1} \{ \mid \{X_1, ..., X_m \} \mid = k\}$. Now I need to prove that the random variables : $(Y_k-Y_{k-1})_{ 2 \leq k \leq n}$ are independent.

Some thoughts :

First I think the random variables are following a geometric law of parameter : $\frac{n-k+1}{n}$. Doest it help ? I don't know... It's not really intuitive to me that they are independent since th variables $Y_k$ are not independent.

Thank you !

Comment: @drhab You are right ! I edited, hope it's correct now.

Comment: I think this concerns the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem). $Y_k-Y_{k-1}=t_k$ where $t_k$ is the notation used in the link. I hope this makes the independence more intuitive for you.